# Mantener abierto menú de navegación bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, adminlte

Espero se encuentren bien. Quiero mantener el menú de navegación abierto cuando selecciono una opción, el menu es vista de árbol (treeview-menu) el problema es que cuando doy click en cualquier opción del menú se refresca la página y cierra el menú debido a que abre el .php programado. El menú lo tengo de la siguiente forma:

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree">
    <li class="header">MENÚ DE NAVEGACIÓN</li> <!-- MENU DE NAVEGACION -->
<!---------------------------------------------------------INFORMACIÓN---------------------------------------------------------->
    <li class="treeview">
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i><span>Información</span> <!-- OPCION DE TIPO DE VISTA -->
            <span class="pull-right-container">
                <small class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></small>
            </span>
        </a>
        <ul class="treeview-menu">
        <!----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
            <li class="treeview"> <!-- CUARTO OPCION BOTON GRAFICAS -->
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i><span>Emisiones</span>
                    <span class="pull-right-container">
                        <small class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></small>
                    </span>
                </a>
                <ul class="treeview-menu">
                    <li class="active"><a href="emisiones.php" id="Padding"><i class="fa fa-money"></i> Emisiones</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="tipos.php" id="Padding"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i> Tipos</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="sector.php" id="Padding"><i class="fa fa-cubes"></i> Sectores</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="calificadoras.php" id="Padding"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> Calificadoras</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="prelibros.php" id="Padding"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> Prelibros</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        <!----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->          
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Cómo puedo mantener el menú abierto de la opción que se seleccione cuando me lleve a la página programada de dicha opción?.

Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Quizás esto te pueda ayudar. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39979124/javascript-sidebar-stay-open-on-page-change). Acá mencionan que podrías guardar el estado del sidebar y cargarlo en su estado al cargar la nueva página

Answer (score 0):

encontré la solución en el foro de AdminLTE. Es más sencillo de lo que parece.

Agregue una clase "active" junto a la clase treeview para que con CSS cada vez que recargue la página la despliegue completamente. También una clase "Active" en el li> donde se coloca la referencia .php para que de igual manera con CSS la pinte cuando la cargue.

Esto lo hice en cada archivo que se manda a llamar dentro del link de manera individual para que las clases se activen cuando se carga.

El código es el siguiente:

```
                  <li class="treeview active">
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i><span>Sistema</span> 
                        <span class="pull-right-container">
                            <small class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></small>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="treeview-menu">
                        <li class="treeview active">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i> <span>Usuarios</span>
                                <span class="pull-right-container">
                                    <small class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></small>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="treeview-menu">
                                <li class="active"><a href="usuarios.php" id="Padding"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Usuarios</a></li>
                                        <li class="Active"><a href="acceso.php" id="Padding"><i class="fa fa-key"></i> Accesos</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

CSS:

```
.Active
{
    background-color: #05648D;
}

/*ABRE LOS MENUS DONDE ESTA SITUADO LA PÁGINA*/
.treeview-menu .active
{
    display: block !important;
    list-style: none !important;
    acolchado: 0 !important;
    margen: 0 !important;
    padding-left: 5px !important;
}
```

Notece que la clase active dentro de treeview-menu también debe ir en los submenus y la clase Active para el li> lo ilumina indicando la opción que abrió.

En conclusión, al dar click en la opción dentro del menú y/o submenú carga la página y despliega el árbol donde dimos click marcando la opción.

Saludos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto publicación no es una respuesta, debes añadirla como edición de tu pregunta.

Comment: Gracias, ya edite la respuesta con la solución al problema. Saludos